# I am trying to troubleshoot why my api are not working

Tags: google-api, google-font-api

In the Google console, my credentials are showing as 100% error. I don't understand why or how to troubleshoot.

I have enabled, regenerated, created new ones, added payment method, restricted, unrestricted, they just don't seem to work and I have no idea why.

NO code, just api keys

This is just to add into a wordpress site, should be simple. All I need are the keys to work.

Comment: Can you include any errors you are getting? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I just see error in the Google Console api & services. And my maps and fonts don't work on my site. I can't seem to find anything that will tell me WHY it is not working. I am not a developer but more front end designer. I am not sure how to even run a test to determine what the error might be.